# How to keep scroll position using flatlist when navigating back in react native ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native. I am facing problem in maintaining the position of flatlist when navigating forward and then come back to that screen.

Current behavior
When navigating forward and then back, the scroll position is lost.

Expected behavior
When navigating on an extensive list of items, the user scrolls down the list and click on some item. The app goes to the next page which shows the product details. If the user decides do navigate back, the page does not scroll to the previous point.

Comment: I'm also new to react-native and looking for the same solution.  I know with ScrollView you have contentOffSet property which might the right idea.  Then you scroll to that position on return?

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentoffset

Comment: There are good answer provided about storing `contentOffset`. However, this is dependant of the navigation library you're using. For instance, `react-navigation` doesn't in all cases unmount views when you're navigating inside *StackNavigator*. But if the view is unmounted, then you should store the `contentOffset` in global state, not the state of the view. **The point is:** to get more precise answers, please define which navigation library you're using.

Comment: @Kerkness contentOffset is only worked on IOS platform. What can I do for Android?

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal  I found it more efficient to calculate the offset myself knowing what index I am viewing. the `onScroll` handler may work for you.  The issue I'm having on Android is scrollToOffset is not working for me

Answer (score 29):

Try handling scroll position changing on a state:

```
<FlatList onScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

**handleScroll** method:

```
handleScroll: function(event: Object) {
 this.setState({ scrollPosition: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y });
}
```

Then you can use **scrollToOffset(this.state.scrollPosition)** when you navigate back.

If you use react-navigation and want to keep the scroll position after navigation, try this hack:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', () => {
    const offset = this.state.scrollPosition
    // To prevent FlatList scrolls to top automatically,
    // we have to delay scroll to the original position 
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ offset, animated: false })
    }, 500)
  })
}
```

Comment: How we check user come back on this page in react navigation?

Comment: I have improved the answer.

Comment: componentWillMount() function is not called when we come back in react-navigation. But we can call function at the screen from where we come back on this screen in componentWillUnmount() using the callback.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
      this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ offset: this.state.scrollPosition, animated: false })
    })
  }

Comment: @KazuyaGosho May I know the reason behind the Time delay to call `scrollToOffset`. I didn't understand your commented explanation in the answer

Comment: @Mighty without the delay scroll position didn't change when I tried. Now it seems that Flatlist keeps the scroll position.

Comment: @KazuyaGosho May i know what do you mean by now? You mean in recent release?

Comment: @Mighty yes. As far as I remember, the delay is needed for RN0.57, but not needed for RN0.59.

Comment: @Mighty I searched commit log, and I added refreshing={false} prop to FlatList to solve the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: @KazuyaGosho I am using `0.59.10`, But still it's not working with out delay. And, Did you mean to say that setting `refreshing={false}` can avoid the `setTimeout`?

Comment: @Mighty yes. I think `refreshing` re-calculates the position and height of the FlatList, so it causes reset of scroll position.

Comment: I tried to use this solution with a few modifications for my case which is a bit different. It did not work for me. I posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241572/flatlist-keep-position-when-new-item-is-added

Comment: Same as @Kasra, it didn't work for me either. I ended up using shouldComponentUpdate for an ad-hoc solution to filter out refreshing the states and that prevented scrolling back to start.

Comment: So you set state and re-render component every time you scroll?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using react-navigation to navigate between a FlatList and a details view. I'm also using react-redux to track state. Here's the process I've followed.

- Basically listen for changes to the navigator and save in redux the name of the current route
- When you select an item in your FlatList remember the index of the item you selected
- When you return to your FlatList calculate the offset for that index and scroll

That's all a little easier said then done and in my own Component the rows in my FlatList are variable so that complicates calculating the offset but heres an example assuming your rows are the same

My App component which renders the navigator

```
handleNavigationStateChange = (prevState, newState) => {
    this._getCurrentRouteName(newState)
}

_getCurrentRouteName = (navState) => {
    if (navState.hasOwnProperty('index')) {
        this._getCurrentRouteName(navState.routes[navState.index])
    } else {
        // This is my redux action to save route name
        this.props.updateCurrentRoute( navState.routeName )
    }
}

<AppNavigator onNavigationStateChange={this.handleNavigationStateChange} />
```

My component with the FlatList looks like this

```
// Renders a row for the FlatList with TouchableHighlight to call viewCreation
renderItem = ( row ) => {
    let creation = row.item
    return (
        <CreationCard onPress={this.viewCreation} index={row.index} creation={creation} />
    )
}

viewCreation = ( index ) => {
    // Get the creation
    let currentCreation = this.props.creations[index]
    // Another reducer saves both my item and index that was selected
    this.props.setSelectedIndex(currentCreation, index)
    // Navigate to the details screen
    this.props.navigation.navigate('CreationDetailScreen')
}

// Assuming all rows are 50 height
getItemLayout = (data, index) => {
    return {length: 50, offset: 50 * index, index}
}

// We mapped the 'currentRoute' property to this component so check
// the props when the component receives new ones.
componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ){
    // If the currentRoute matches the route for this screen
    if( nextProps.currentRoute === 'CreationListScreen' ){
        // If we also know the last index that was selected on this page
        if( this.props.lastCreationIndex ){
            // Calculate the offset for the last index selected
            let y = this.props.lastCreationIndex * 50
            // and finally scroll to the offset
            this._flatList.scrollToOffset({
                offset: y,
                animated: true
            })
        }
    }
}


// IMPORTANT to include getItemLayout
render(){
    return(
    <FlatList
       ref={(fl) => this._flatList = fl}
       data={this.props.creations}
       renderItem={this.renderItem}
       getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
       keyExtractor={creation => creation.id}
       />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

set state of scroll position to store position.

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
```

first set the ref of the flatlist

```
const flatListRef = useRef(null);
```

then on  `onContentSizeChange` prop in Flatlist set it this way

```
onContentSizeChange={() => {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({
          offset: scrollPosition,
          animated: false,
        });
      }}
```

set  `onLayout` prop for the offset to scrollPosition

```
   onLayout={() => {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({
          offset: scrollPosition,
          animated: false,
        });
      }}
```

finally on  `onScroll` prop get the position as it changes

```
        onScroll={event => {
        setScrollPosition(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
      }}
```

now your Flatlist should look like this

```
       <FlatList
      ref={flatListRef}
      onContentSizeChange={() => {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({
          offset: scrollPosition,
          animated: false,
        });
      }}
      onLayout={() => {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({
          offset: scrollPosition,
          animated: false,
        });
      }}
      onScroll={event => {
        setScrollPosition(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Instead of `onScroll` I used `onScrollEndDrag`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid multiple re-renders using setState, instead of onScroll that called multiple times, you can use this two props to covers both cases. 1st case is that the user drag and stop touching screen and the second the user reach the point by dragging. Totally you have only 2 re-renders instead of 20-50 or whatever.

```
onMomentumScrollEnd={e => setScrollPos(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)}
onScrollEndDrag={e => setScrollPos(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using functional component this will be helpful.

Step 1: Create a constant using hooks to maintain the scroll position with initial value zero.

```
  const [scrollPosition,setScrollPosition]=React.useState(0)
```

Step 2: Create a method for updating the scroll postion. When the user scrolled.

```
const handleScroll=(event)=>{
  let yOffset=event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y / heightOfYourListItem;
  setScrollPosition(yOffset)
}
```

Step 3: Call the handleScroll() method when the user scrolls the flat list.

```
    <FlatList
            enableEmptySections={true}
            onScroll={(event)=>handleScroll(event)}
            initialScrollIndex={scrollPosition}
            numColumns={2}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.Id}
            data={Items}
            renderItem={({item}) =>renderListItems(item}
/>
```

Comment: why do we wanna set state and rerender the component on every scroll?

Answer (score 0):

The current behaviour with react-navigation is actually that the scroll position is being remembered when you switch back and forward between screens. It **does** reset though when you switch from a screen that has `headerTransparent` set to a different setting than the state you navigate there from.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by react-navigation, which detaches the previous screen to optimize the navigation.

reference:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#detachinactivescreens

**Solution**:

I solved the issue by disabling the detachment of my screen.

In order to do that make sure the next screen you navigate to, has this property in its navigation options:

`detachPreviousScreen: false`

Example:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
       detachPreviousScreen: false
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `createStackNavigator` from `@react-navigation/stack,` try switching to `createNativeStackNavigator` from `@react-navigation/native-stack.` In `createNativeStackNavigator,` each new screen is placed on top of a stack.

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function SomeStack() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -7):

In Flatlist set `scrollsToTop={false}` this will retain position when you navigate back from detail screen. I am using Expo version 25.