# React Native Flatlist delete item without scrolling to top

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

When I delete an item from my `flatlist` data, i use `setState` to assign the new data set. When i use `setState`, my flatlist scroll to top, which I don't want. I want the flatlist to remain at the same position. I am using the following code for flatlist:

```
                           <KeyboardAwareFlatList
                                keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
                                onScrollBeginDrag={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
                                style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
                                data={stockItems}
                                extraData={this.state}
                                removeClippedSubviews={true}
                                maxToRenderPerBatch={100}
                                updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
                                initialNumToRender={100}
                                windowSize={7}
                                ref={(ref) => { this.flatlist = ref; }}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                                legacyImplementation={true}
                                renderItem={({ item }) =>{
                                    return(
                                        <StocktakeBagItem
                                            item={item}
                                            searchFields={this.state.fields}
                                            onPress={(nItem)=>{
                                                this.setState({ 
                                                    showStockItemEdit:true,
                                                    stockItemEdit: nItem
                                                })
                                            }}
                                            realm={this.state.realm}
                                            isEditBag={editStockBag}
                                            language={language}
                                        />
                                    )
                                }}/>
```

Any suggestion on how can I achieve the expected behavior? Thank you

Comment: You can keep track of the scroll position then populate it after the delete event. KeyboardAwareFlatlist inherits FlatList after all. You may find this helpful 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061234/how-to-keep-scroll-position-using-flatlist-when-navigating-back-in-react-native

Comment: Is it possible to remain at the same position without scrolling? @keysl

Comment: If you set the animated to false, then scrolling animation will not fire, hence giivng an illusion that you did not scroll.

Comment: It's working as expected @keysl