# Flatlist is not Scrolling to desired offset when scrollToOffset is used

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

here is my `FlatList` code

```
 <FlatList
    ref={ref => this.flatListRef = ref}
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderItems(item, index)}
    onScroll={(e) => this.handleScroll(e)}
/>
```

here is `handleScroll` method where i get the `ScrollPosition`

```
handleScroll(event) {
    this.props.updateAppState('scrollPosition', event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
}
```

And finally in `componentDidMount` `ScrollToOffset` is called

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ animated: false, offset: this.props.app.scrollPosition});
}
```

`FlatList` never Scrolls it's list. I am really helpless now. Can anybody let me know what can i do to make it `scroll` to the desired `offset`?. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad you found out the solution, the thing is even i faced this problem to find out that using setTimeout actually works.

That reminded me of the basics of javascript. What happens is an event loop. When your page load , it calls every method inside an event loop.

Without setTimeout , the code actually gets executed even before all the components are actually rendered for the first time hence you see no effect. But with setTimeout even with 0ms as time, it gets added in the eventloop at last. And after every async function, that setTimeout is again brought back and executed. HEnce you see the difference.

hope it helps feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Can you guide me where can i learn about this event loop in depth?

Answer (score 8):

After number of attempts i found the solution with this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061234/how-to-keep-scroll-position-using-flatlist-when-navigating-back-in-react-native?answertab=votes#tab-top) that time delay makes it work.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ offset: this.props.app.scrollPosition, animated: false })
}, 0)
```

But I didn't really understand why this time delay is required. In official [documents](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltooffset) itself nothing has been mentioned about time delay. Though problem has been resolved for now I would like to know the reason behind this time delay.

Can anybody help me to know the reason behind this time delay?. Thank you.

Comment: It is better to use InteractionManager (https://reactnative.dev/docs/interactionmanager) like this:
InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
  this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ offset: number, animated: false });
});

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` and `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` still has some weird behaviour for me.

Instead I triggered `scrollToOffset` in the `onLayout` prop of the `FlatList`.

`onLayout={() => this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ offset: this.props.app.scrollPosition, animated: false })}`