# Retaining scroll position in flatlist in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a project which mostly uses class component and I have a flatlist in which I want to retain the scroll position after the user has navigated forward and come back later.The same thing works perfectly fine on ios (i.e the scroll position is reatined) but not in android.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isMounted: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadScrollPosition();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({ isMounted: false }, () => {
      this.handleComponentUnmount();
    });
  }

  handleComponentUnmount = async () => {
    if (!this.state.isMounted) {
      try {
        const scrollPosition = await this.getScrollPosition();
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', scrollPosition.toString());
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error saving scroll position:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  getScrollPosition = async () => {
    try {
      const scrollPosition = await this.flatListRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0, animated: false });
      return scrollPosition || 0;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error getting scroll position:', error);
      return 0;
    }
  };

  loadScrollPosition = async () => {
    try {
      const scrollPosition = await AsyncStorage.getItem('scrollPosition');
      if (scrollPosition) {
        this.flatListRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: parseInt(scrollPosition, 10), animated: false });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error loading scroll position:', error);
    }
  };

  flatListRef = React.createRef();

  // Sample data for FlatList
  data = [...Array(50).keys()].map((item) => ({ key: item.toString(), title: `Item ${item}` }));

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          ref={this.flatListRef}
          data={this.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ height: 50, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

This is the code I've tried.How can I fix this issue? Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep scroll position using flatlist when navigating back in react native ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061234/how-to-keep-scroll-position-using-flatlist-when-navigating-back-in-react-native)